# Create a Webmethod to get the JSON in c#

Tags: c#, wcf

I am creating a sample WCF service to receive requests from Client application.
The Client would send a JSON Message as a request with POST WebMethod.
Part of client code as below:

```
                publishRequest.Method = "POST";
                publishRequest.ContentLength = unit.Length;
                publishRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                Stream publishStream = publishRequest.GetRequestStream();
                publishRequestWriter = new StreamWriter(publishStream);
                publishRequestWriter.Write(unit);
                publishRequestWriter.Flush();
                publishRequestWriter.Close();
```

I need to create a Webmethod in WCF Service to handle the request. Just get the request and store.

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "echo")]
        string HandleMessage(string request);
    }
```

and
 public string HandleMessage(string request)

```
    {
     ..........
     .....
    }
```

How to achieve this?